# Removing 0s from dataframe without removing NAs

Tags: r

I try to create a subset, where I remove all answers == 0 for variable B, given another variable A == 1. However, I **want** to keep the NAs in Variable B (just remove the 0s).

I tried it with this `df2 <- subset(df, B[df$A == 1] > 0)` but the result makes no sense. Can someone help?

```
i <- c(1:10)
A <- c(0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1)
B <- c(0, 10, 13, NA, NA, 9, 0, 0, 3, NA)
df <- data.frame(i, A, B)
```

Comment: greater than/smaller than do not work when `NA` are present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`subset` takes a condition and returns only the rows where the value is `TRUE`. If you try `NA == 0`, or `NA != 0` it will always return `NA`, which is neither `TRUE` nor `FALSE`, however as `subset` would have it it only returns rows where the value is `TRUE`. There are multiple ways around this:

```
subset(df, !(A == 1 & B == 0) | is.na(B))
```

or:

```
subset(df, !(A == 1 & B %in% 0))
```

There's plenty more options available however

Answer (score 0):

This should work, if I understand it correctly:

```
subset(df, (df$A == 1) & ((df$B != 0) | (is.na(df$B))))
```

outputs:

```
i A  B
2 1 10
3 1 13
4 1 NA
10 1 NA
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to specify every single column, you can just change the `0` to `NA` and the `NA` (temporarily) to a number (for example 999/-999) and switch back after you are finished.

```
i <- c(1:10)
A <- c(0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1)
B <- c(0, 10, 13, NA, NA, 9, 0, 0, 3, NA)
df <- data.frame(i, A, B)

df[is.na(df)] <- 999
df[df==0] <- NA
df <- na.omit(df)
df[df==999] <- NA

    i A  B
2   2 1 10
3   3 1 13
4   4 1 NA
10 10 1 NA
```

Answer (score -1):

If `i` is unique, identify wich cases you want to remove and select the rest, try:

```
df[df$i != subset(df, A==1 & B==0)$i, ]
```

Output:

```
    i A  B
1   1 0  0
2   2 1 10
3   3 1 13
4   4 1 NA
5   5 0 NA
6   6 0  9
9   9 0  3
10 10 1 NA
```